# Calling method or functions in c#

Tags: c#

I'm new in C#, could you please tell me that what's my problem here.
I know it's very simple for you but it's not for me :(

My short code :

```
class A 
{ 
    private int B; 
    public void b(){ }
    public void c(){ B = b( );}
    static void Main ( string [ ] args ) 
    {
        c(); 
    }
}
```

My Error is :

> An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'GMBL.Program.Start()'

How can I fix it?

Comment: Variable B of what type?

Comment: I'd bet you don't have experience in object oriented programming or the mistake would be obvious.
There must be resources to learn C# and object orientation, step by step. Why not pick one and follow it?

Answer (score 6):

`Main` is a `static` method – it is not associated with an instance of your class.

`c` is an **instance** method – it operates on an instance of your class.
You can only call `c` on an instance.

Comment: You should provide some code too with the description. Just my 2 cents.

Comment: @Raj: No.  I want the OP to _understand_ the issue instead of blindly copying code.  Chances are that if I provide code, he'll ignore the explanation and use the code.  (of course, the other answers ruin my attempt)

Answer (score 2):

*change* `public void c()`

*to* `public static void c()`

**or**

Create a `new` ***instance*** of `class A` and call the ***instance member*** `c();`

```
static void Main ( string [ ] args ) 
{
    var foo = new A();
    foo.c();
}
```

As @SLaks pointed out you cannot call `instance members` of a `type` from a `static member` of the same `type`, or some other `type`, without a reference of said `type`.

Comment: _You should explain._  Don't do things blindly.

Answer (score 0):

You are referencing a non-static function `c()` from the static function `Main()`.  Either make `c()` static or create an instance of `A` and call `c()` on it:

```
A a = new A();
a.c();
// do something with a
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to create an object for your class A.

```
ClassA a1 = new classA();
a1.c();
```

Answer (score 0):

Move the `Main` function out to another static class, and within it create an instance of `A`, and call the method:

```
class A 
{ 
    private B; 
    public void b(){ }
    public void c(){ B = b( );}
} 

class Program 
{
    public static void Main ( string [ ] args ) 
    {
        A a = new A();
        a.c(); 
    }
}
```

The app's entry point should generally live in its own independent class.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to instantiate a new class, simple make the `c` static, example:

```
public static void c()
```

Comment: yes i don't want to instantiate a new class , but when i changed it to public static void c(); it didn't recognize the private int B, in c();

Answer (score 0):

first, you can't write private B, you must give be a type.
second, b does not return any value, so you can't assign it to B

Answer (score 0):

Two issues are there in your code.

**Issue#1** : You can not use non-static members in static methods.

To use **c()** in your **main** method, either you have to change **c()** to a static method like

```
public static void c(){....}
```

OR declare an object for your class **A** and then call **c()** with that object instance like

```
A objA = new A();
objA.c();
```

**Issue#2** : The statement

```
B = b( );
```

is wrong because the method **b()** is not returning any value.

First change

```
private B;
```

to

```
private int B; // Or some thing like this
```

and then

```
public void b(){ }
```

to

```
public int b(){}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Static methods are not associated with a class instance. In your case method C() is a non-static method i.e. it is associated with a class instance and to access C() from a static method you have to first create an object of your class A. Then call C() from that object.

So inside Main() method use below 2 lines

```
A obj = new A();
obj.C();
```